# Шрифт на iPhone мелче, чем нужно

Tags: css, iphone, safari

Подскажите, почему на iPhone шрифт номеров телефонов в подвале сайта мелкий, хотя свойствами он стоит больше гораздо.
Через проверку через браузер Mozill в режиме мобильного просмотра все нормально, но на физическом iPhone мелкое.
Сайт вот:
http://myiconskin.sopteh.beget.tech/
P.S. Проблема наблюдается только на Safari

Comment: Вот почему: http://prntscr.com/kwkvga

Comment: @Nilsan, а почему же он не цепляет стили media ?

Comment: потому что у вас в media не задан стиль 'a' для div phone. Просто задайте его

Comment: @Nilsan, спасибо. Подскажите пожалуйста, а почему у меня через Firefox нет ссылки на номере телефона. iPhone ее самостоятельно добавляет?)) http://prntscr.com/l03wq5

Comment: я если честно не знаю, но у меня такое подохрение что он сам добавляет т.к. на днях при добавлении ИНН на сайте заметил что он превращает его активную ссылку tel :-) А то что черех FF нет, так и в хроме не будет. Браузер не эмулирует работу утсройства а просто эмулирует разрешение и не более того.

Comment: @Nilsan спасибо!)) Можете свой коммент в ответ превратить, отмечу как правильный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что у вас в media не задан стиль 'a' для div phone. Просто задайте его